# Can you “wish somebody congratulations”?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the construction “wish somebody congratulations” common at all?
I thought you could wish somebody good luck etc., or you could congratulate them.

Then I read president-elect Trump tweet

> The President of Taiwan CALLED ME today to wish me congratulations on winning the Presidency.

Comment: It's fair enough in a tweet, I suppose (apart from using more letters than necessary).

Comment: It sounds perfectly normal to my (northern English) ear

Comment: To mine, it would be natural to "give congratulations" rather than to wish them. I interpret "wish congratulations" as meaning "to hope someone else will congratulate" just as "wish luck" means "to hope luck will be experienced".

Comment: In answer to your question (*is it common?*) — [no](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish+*+congratulations%2Cgive+*+congratulations&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwish%20you%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cgive%20%2A%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgive%20my%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgive%20their%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgive%20his%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgive%20our%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0); in answer to the impled questions of *is it right?* — yes: while not idiomatic, it is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, **no** it is not common, paticularly in relation to the more idiomatic phrase *give congratulations*.

As [Google Ngrams shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish+*+congratulations%2Cgive+*+congratulations&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwish%20you%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cgive%20%2A%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgive%20my%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgive%20their%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgive%20his%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgive%20our%20congratulations%3B%2Cc0), historically, *give* is far more common, although it has become less popular recently.

*Wish* has gone up in popularity over the last half-century but is still below *give*.